# Html helper dose not contain a definition for autocompleteFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, typeahead

I'm Following this article http://timdwilson.github.io/typeahead-mvc-model/
and in the (e) part of this article it uses  `@Html.AutocompleteFor` but my project dosen't recognize it. it has the Error : `Html helper dose not contain a definition for autocompleteFor`

Appreciate any idea to help. thanks.

Comment: `@Html.AutocompleteFor()` is a `HtmlHelper` extension method. Somewhere in the code you have downloaded you will find a method with a signature like `public static MvcHtmlString AutocompleteFor (this HtmlHelper htmlHelper ...... )` - you need to find it and then add a `using` statement in your view that is the assembly name of that method (probably `@using Controllers.HtmlHelpers;`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I found an object `HtmlHelpers.cs` contains `public static class AutocompleteHelpers
    {}`  includes `public static MvcHtmlString AutocompleteFor<TModel, TProperty1, TProperty2>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty1>> valueExpression,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty2>> idExpression, string actionName, string controllerName, bool requestFocus, object additionalViewData){}` but how I can find assembly name? thanks for your care again

Comment: At the top of that file (below ant `using` statements) there will be `namespace xxxx {` Then in the view just add `@using xxxx` (replace `xxxx` with the actual value you see)

Comment: that works thank you. wooow I have no idea how to guess all these details. please answer and i'm really sorry for bother you. thanks again @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.AutocompleteFor()` is an extension method for the `HtmlHelper` class.

Somewhere in the code you have downloaded, you will find a method that will have a signature similar to

```
public static MvcHtmlString AutocompleteFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper ...... )
```

Looking at the images in your link, its most likely in the `/Controllers/HtmlHelper.cs` file. At the top of that file, beneath any `using` statements, you will find the name of the `namespace`

```
namespace xxxx
{
    public static class .....
```

In the view, add (where `xxxx` is the name of the namespace)

```
@using xxxx
```

If you want to make this available in all your views, you can add it to `web.config.cs`file so that you do not need the `using` statement in the view

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            ....
            <add namespace="xxxx" /> // add the namespace here
        </namespaces>
```